# Redshift spectrum struggles with huge joins

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I am trying to find out if I misconfigured something or am I hitting limits of single node redshift cluster?

I am using:

- single node ra3 instance,
- spectrum layer for files in s3,
- files I am using are partitioned in S3 in parquet format and archived using snappy,
- data I am trying to join it into is loaded into my redshift cluster (16m rows I will mention later is in my cluster),
- data in external tables has `numRows` property according to the documentation

I am trying to perform a spatial join 16m rows into 10m rows using `ST_Contains()` and it just never finishes. I know that query is correct because it is able to join 16m rows with 2m rows in 6 seconds.

(query in Athena on same data completes in 2 minutes)

Case with 10m rows has been running for 60 minutes now and seems like it will just never finish. Any thoughts?

Comment: Please give examples of the data (fabricated examples, of course) and an example of the query.  Also, describe how both the Athena and RedShift data structures are set up.  Pay particular attention to indexes, compression, sort-order, etc.  It's simply likely that your query and data structure combine in such a way that the query that can only be answered by brute-force checking all combinations *(All 160 **Trillion** of them)*.  At present the question lacks enough details to be effectively answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It eventually finishes but takes very long time. I understand that this is due to hitting unknown limit of rows where Redshift changes strategy of joining to **Slow Strategy**. This is how I understand these strategies:

**Fast Strategy**

Redshift takes table you are trying to join and sends it to every spectrum worker node resulting in a very fast join. Each worker performs join on its part of data and then sends results back.

**Slow Strategy**

Table you are trying to join is too big to be sent to a worker node. Each worker node sends its data back to main node and this node performs the join.

It has to perform join, then wait for data from another worker node, perform join, (...).

**How to speed it up**

1. Do you really need to perform such huge joins?
2. Try to swap order of tables in the join clause. It is possible that swapping order may change strategy.
3. Get more nodes. I tested this and the join is significantly faster when you have more nodes. I understand that data sent back from spectrum workers is spread among your nodes resulting in much faster join.